# How to test whether user security settings will cause window.localStorage not to work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: security, internet-explorer, dom, local-storage

In Internet Explorer, if the user has protected mode checked on the Security tab for the Internet domain, `window.localStorage.setItem()` silently fails. Is there a Microsoft-specific way of testing whether the feature is enabled?  Testing for its mere presence returns true.

Comment: How does it silently fail? Is it that if you immediately check for the item, it is not there? Or is it that it *appears* to be set (if you check for it, it is there) but as soon as the window is closed, the item is lost?

Comment: I've been checking it as though it should persist, rather than have a lifetime only as long as the session.  I close the browser and reopen the page 15 seconds later, and there are no values. But in other browsers (Opera, Chrome, FF) the values *are* being written to storage correctly and they do persist.

Comment: So I take it that doing `setItem` to set a test value and then immediately doing `getItem` to get it would work, and this does not tell you anything since the issue is persistence.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(window.localStorage&&window.sessionStorage){
    // do storage stuff;
}
else {
   alert('your userAgent does not support DOM Storage or it is disabled by your browser settings or Group Policy');
}
```

In MSIE (8 and higher) browsers DOM storage is user and GPO configurable from the Advanced tab of Internet Options>"enable DOM Storage"...

localStorage and sessionStorage are 'undefined' in html files using the file: protocol. Develop and test using your localhost or a web server.

Hi,
my bad....

```
    if ('undefined'!==typeof(win.localStorage)) {
```

OT: I see my forum puppy is still humping my leg...

Comment: The test returns true even when they're disabled. That's the problem.